# DAX calculate index based on month

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery

in power query i have a table like this:

```
date       | month    |
01/01/2017 | jan 2017 |
02/01/2017 | jan 2017 |
03/01/2017 | jan 2017 |
...        | ...      |
01/02/2017 | feb 2017 |
...
01/02/2017 | mar 2017 |
...
01/01/2018 | jan 2018 |
```

now i want to add a calculated row that gives me an index based on month. 
So for every new month the index needs to increase with 1.

```
index | date       | month    |
01    | 01/01/2017 | jan 2017 |
01    | 02/01/2017 | jan 2017 |
01    | 03/01/2017 | jan 2017 |
..    | ...        | ...      |
02    | 01/02/2017 | feb 2017 |
..    | ...        | ...
03    | 01/03/2017 | mar 2017 |
..    | ...        | ... 
13    | 01/01/2018 | jan 2018 |
```

Anybody knows how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with calculated column after you import your data with Power Query. First, please add this ranking column. `Year&month num = YEAR(Sheet1[Date])&"-"&FORMAT(MONTH(Sheet1[Date]),"00")`

Then please add this calculated column

```
Index = COUNTROWS(
                FILTER(VALUES(Sheet1[Year&month num]),
                       Sheet1[Year&month num]<EARLIER(Sheet1[Year&month num])

))+1
```

Now it should only add new index if it is a new month.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but if i try it it just start caount from 1 and it increases every day. Any idea why ?

Comment: It is increasing for 1 each day because countrows is set to count each new date (not each new month). I have adjusted formula in Answer above so now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this:

`=Month(date)+12*(Year(date)-2017)`

The second part adds a count of 12 to each passing year, with the `-2017` bit assuming your first date is in January 2017 (leaving you with 12x(2017-2017) = 12x0 = 0 for the first year.

Comment: This gave me 13 to begin with, so i adjusted it: 

`=Month(date)+12*(Year(date)-2016)-12`

Thanks

Comment: Ah, you're correct @Bjorn Morrhaye. It should be -2017 rather than -2016, I've added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Power Query based approach:

Starting with this table as "Table1":

[image]

Click on the "Month" column, then the "Transform" tab, then the "Group By" button; and complete the dialog box like this:

[image]

...and click "OK."

You'll now have a table that looks like this:

[image]

Add an index column by clicking the "Add Column" tab and then the "Index Column" button.

You'll now have a table that looks like this:

[image]

Click the [image] button at the top right of the "AllData" column to expand the tables in the "AllData" column.

You'll now have a table that looks like this:

[image]

Drag the columns to arrange them into the order you want:

[image]